# How to resolve undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_Replace?

Tags: python, numpy, installation

I recently tried to remove an existing python version in my user account on a linux server.

I reinstalled packages like scipy and numpy. But when i try and import numpy then I get an error because of `_io` package.

```
$>python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 13 2014, 11:26:58)
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import _io
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /home/arenduc1/python/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_Replace
```

This is my current configuration of python paths:

```
$>python -m site
sys.path = [
    '/home/arenduc1/source-pkgs/numpy',
    '/home/arenduc1/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Cython-0.20.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
    '/home/arenduc1/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gensim-0.8.9-py2.7.egg',
    '/home/arenduc1/python',
    '/home/arenduc1/python/lib/python2.7',
    '/home/arenduc1/python/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
    '/home/arenduc1/python/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
    '/home/arenduc1/python/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
    '/home/arenduc1/python/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
    '/home/arenduc1/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
    '/home/arenduc1/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/home/arenduc1/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/home/arenduc1/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages' (exists)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

This is my pythonpath and pythonhome variable:

```
$>echo $PYTHONPATH
/home/arenduc1/python
$>echo $PYTHONHOME
/home/arenduc1/python
```

How can I resolve this? I would ideally like to remove (local version) of python completely and reinstall it afresh.

Thanks in advance.